# Changing a column name in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to change the column name of a temp table. Other posts have suggested the format should be as follows, but it is not working. Any tips would be appreciated.

```
SP_rename '#subscriptions.PricePerSeat', 'PricePerSeat_original', 'Column'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you renaming column in temp table?

Comment: What do you mean it's not working?  Do you get any errors?

Comment: exec sp_rename........

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Did you read the first sentence in the post?

Comment: @RickS, sorry, missed that... Upvouted your unswer

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri No worries, just wanted to point out they did say they were using a temp table.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
USE TEMPDB
Exec SP_rename '#subscriptions.PricePerSeat', 'PricePerSeat_original', 'COLUMN'
```

OR

```
Exec tempdb..SP_rename '#subscriptions.PricePerSeat', 'PricePerSeat_original', 'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
EXEC sp_RENAME '#subscriptions.PricePerSeat', 'PricePerSeat_original', 'COLUMN'
```